# How to to foresee External ID in HttpPost?

Tags: apex, rest, post, httppost

When we post a Box record we also send it an External Id from another side. How to to make it in HttpPost method?

I have an object1 in Org1. In Org1 are all my callouts. object1 has a button POST. When I press it - I create the object2 in Org2, but object2 has also an External Id field, and this field == Id from object1.

My code:

```
@HttpPost
global static Box__c postBox(String title){
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

    Box__c b = new Box__c(
        Title__c = title,
        );
    insert b;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: I have an object1 in Org1. In Org1 are all my callouts. object1 has a button POST. When I press it - I create the object2 in Org2, but object2 has also an External Id field, and this field == Id from object1.

Comment: Okay, I've seen your questions pop up all weekend, and I'm just wondering why you're not using the standard [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm), which looks like exactly what you should be using in this case.

Comment: I need to my post-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding other options like the native REST API that [sfdxfox suggested](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235087/how-to-to-foresee-external-id-in-httppost#comment357526_235087), you could perform the upsert from Apex.

E.g.

```
@HttpPost
global static Box__c postBox(String title, Id org1BoxId) {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

    Box__c b = new Box__c(
        Title__c = title,
        ExternalId_From_Org1__c = org1BoxId
        );

    // Specify the ExternalId_From_Org1__c field as the external ID
    upsert b ExternalId_From_Org1__c;
    return b;
}
```

Here `ExternalId_From_Org1__c` is an additional field in Org 2 that is marked as an external ID.

See also:

- [Upserting Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm) towards the bottom for "Use of upsert with an external ID..."